# Cast with typeof

Tags: c#, dynamic, casting

I have some type that `Type someType` that I want to cast in runtime

for example I want to do :

```
var customers = GetCustomers() as someType[]
```

How to do this?

Comment: I take it someType is determined at runtime? Even if you could find a way, this seems like a bad idea. How do you know what type it is to use it later?

Comment: If you can say what problem you''re trying to solve it will be better to answer.

Comment: Had the same problem when using reflection to set properties from a DB. I know the name of the property but I don't know its type. I know the name of the DB column but I don't know its type. So, good question. (And good answer.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot use `as` to cast a type known at runtime: the expression would be invalid at compile-time since you'd have to use `typeof(T)` which cannot be used together with `as`.

What you can use though is `System.Convert.ChangeType(object, Type)`. Here the second parameter *can* use `typeof(T)` and combined with a control statement you can convert the input at runtime to the correct type.

You should ask yourself whether this is something you want though: types known only at runtime will leave you with little use.

[MSDN: System.Convert.ChangeType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.changetype.aspx)

Answer (score -1):

The **as** operator attempts to cast an object to a specific type, and returns null if it fails.

Example:

StringBuilder b = someObject as StringBuilder;
if (b != null) ...

Also related:

The cast operator attempts to cast an object to a specific type, and throws an exeption if it fails.

Example:

StringBuilder b = (StringBuilder)someObject.

Refer this link :[Difference between is and as keyword](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3786361/difference-between-is-and-as-keyword)

Comment: A good explanation of the as operator, but I don't think this answers the question of doing a cast to a run-time determined type (which this won't allow of course)

Comment: @BradleyDotNET With the help of As, u can cast the object at runtime, but if you want to use runtime type , you can go with "Dynamic". dynamic is a new static type that acts like a placeholder for a type not known until runtime.