# which is better from performance point of view - "is" or "as" cast

Tags: c#, .net, performance

i have very basic doubt - from performance point of view "is" cast or "as" cast is better to use. Though "as" does not throw exception but it does boxing and hence performance gets affected but still not sure.

if possible please give example for this

Comment: Completely depends on how it is being used - `is` returns a boolean to determine a type, `as` casts it to that type if possible to use the object

Comment: its highly unlikely that either are going to have a measurable impact on the performance of your application. Try it and see?

Comment: Wrong duplicate, should be [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3786361/1997232).

Comment: it does not look like duplicate..

Comment: @Sinatr : There is no clear answer to the question in the post. But if you need the cast anyway go for `as`. If you don't go for `is`!

Comment: @TaW, linked question contains answers which explains difference between `as` and `is`. Performance conclusion is given by tests usually.