# Is there ever a reason to use is versus as?

Tags: c#, type-conversion

When considering the `is` versus `as` in C#, you can use either to confirm if a type is convertible to another type.

```
// using is
Employee e = new Manager();
if (e is Manager) { 
    var m = (Manager) e; 
    // m is now type `Manager`
}

// using as
Employee e = new Manager(); 
Manager m = e as Manager; 
// m is now type `Manager`
if (m != null) { 

}
```

I understand how both operators work and how to use them. Consider the `is` operator checks the type twice while `as` checks once, and they both have the same restrictions regarding what types of conversions they support, is there ever a compelling reason to use `is`?

The marked duplicate is asking what is the difference between the two operators. My question is specifically asking "Understanding what both do, why use `is`?" They are not the same question, nor do they have the same answer.

Comment: have you not checked out the msdn site on how to safely cast by using IS and  AS https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc488006.aspx
`the as operator is more efficient because it actually returns the cast value if the cast can be made successfully. The is operator returns only a Boolean value. It can therefore be used when you just want to determine an object's type but do not have to actually cast it.`

Comment: I understand how to use both operators to safely cast types. I'm more questioning if there's ever a compelling reason to use `is` rather than `as`.

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3786390/4705221

Comment: I don't think `is` casts the type, it only checks it.   `as` casts it.

Comment: I also understand what both operators do. I am asking that if `is` checks the type twice versus once for `as`, is there ever a reason to use `is`.

Comment: I think to make a long explanation short.. the `is` is assuming where the `as` is actually doing a valid cast

Comment: Use is when you don't want to cast but want to know if it is compatible. Use as when you want to cast a nullable type

Comment: @PatrickMurphy not exactly duplicate, but maybe worth adding that difference - I'll make comment on that post.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You must use `is` instead of `as` when the destination type is a non-nullable value type:

```
object obj = 0;
int i = obj as int; // compilation error because int can't represent null

if (obj is int)
{
    int j = (int)obj; // works
}
```

Comment: OH! Well, that clears that up. Thanks. :)

Comment: @jdphenix also it makes your program more readable to use the is operator if you're just validating an object's type but not using the castes object.

Answer (score 3):

The `is` operator performs a type-check.  The `as` operator performs a type-check and (if possible) a cast.

> is there ever a compelling reason to use `is`?

I can think of a couple scenarios.  First, as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31013754/2630934) already points out, you can't as-cast non-nullable value types.

But your original example, although extremely common, is heavily biased towards `as`.  It all depends what you are going to do after your cast and/or type-check.

Let's say you will be calling the following method if your cast succeeds:

```
private void PerformManagerDuty(Manager m) 
{
    //Stuff happens
}
```

Performing the `as` cast then the null check takes an extra line of code than `is`:

```
//as casting with null check
var m = e as Manager; 
if (m != null)
{
    PerformManagerDuty(m);
}

//is check before cast
if (e is Manager)
{ 
    PerformManagerDuty((Manager)e);
}
```

Also, if you prefer, after performing a type-check with `is`, you can perform an `as` cast with no performance loss:

```
if (e is Manager)
{ 
    PerformManagerDuty(e as Manager);
}
```